# Unable to retrieve variable from class and experiencing runtime/logic errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to create a program that acts as a simple calculator. I'm trying to ask the user to input what type of calculation they want to do and what number they want to calculate, and they can continue to repeat the calculation as long as they desire.

I believe I have all the code required but I'm experiencing troubles when trying to retrieve the variable to be calculated. I'm also having troubles with my loops when it catches the Exception, it bugs out when caught. I'm having difficulties trying to fix these problems. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class GetDouble {

public static double NewNumber;
public static int z=1;
public static int a=1;

static Scanner Input = new Scanner( System.in );

public static double GetDoubleNumber (double GetDouble)
{


    do {
        try{

                System.out.println("Please enter a number for the calculation.");
                double NewNumber = Input.nextDouble();

                a=2;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number. ");

                a=1;
            }
            }while(a==1);

    return NewNumber;

}

public static double DivideTwoNumbers (double Result, double NewNumber, double NewResult)
{

    do {
    try{
                GetDoubleNumber(NewNumber);
                NewResult = Result / NewNumber; 

                z=2;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number, the number can not be 0 when dividing. ");
        }
        }while(z==1);

    return NewResult;

}

}

//Driver Class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalculator extends GetDouble{

static Scanner Input = new Scanner( System.in );
public static double Result = 0.0;
public static double NewResult;
public static double NewNumber;
public static int y=1;
public static int z=1;


public static void main (String[] args) {

         do {

            System.out.println("Enter the type of calculation. (Examples: +, -, *, or /) ");
    String Calculation = Input.nextLine();

    do {

        switch (Calculation.charAt(0)) {

    case '+':

        GetDoubleNumber(NewNumber);
        NewResult = Result + NewNumber;

        System.out.println("New Result: " + NewResult);

        z=2;

        break;

    case '-':

        GetDoubleNumber(NewNumber);
        NewResult = Result - NewNumber;

        System.out.println("New Result: " + NewResult);

        z=2;

        break;

    case '*':

        GetDoubleNumber(NewNumber);
        NewResult = Result * NewNumber;

        System.out.println("New Result: " + NewResult);

        z=2;

        break;

    case '/':

        DivideTwoNumbers (Result, NewNumber, NewResult);
        System.out.println("New Result: " + NewResult);

        z=2;

        break;

    default:
            System.out.println("Please enter the type of calculation. (Examples: +, -, *, or /)  ");

            z=1;
        }

    }while(z==1);


              System.out.println("Enter 'Yes' to continue calculation \n "
                + "or 'Result' to see calculation result.");
         String Answer = Input.nextLine();


         if(Answer.charAt(0) == 'Y' || (Answer.charAt(0) == 'y'))
         {
            y=1;
         }
         if(Answer.charAt(0) == 'R' || (Answer.charAt(0) == 'r'))
         {
             System.out.println("Calculation result: " + Result);
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Please enter 'Yes' to continue calculation \n" 
                     + "or 'Result' to see calculation result.");

         }   


         }while(y==1);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the trouble?

Comment: Don't use global variables as your loop-breaking flags for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you function `GetDoubleNumber` has a double return value, but in the driver class, you are misusing it. 
The function also receives a parameter of type double, but you don't seem to do anything with it.
When calling the function in your driver class, you need to store its result in a variable like so:

`double newNumber = GetDoubleNumber(NewNumber);`

Again, the function does not really need any input arguments, so the above can be simplified to 
`double newNumber = GetDoubleNumber();`
You will have to change the function's definition as well of course to accept no arguments.

If I had to guess, I would venture that you believe the "NewNumber" you pass as an argument to the function when calling it will store the result, but that is not the case.